# Stacked bar chart swap x-axis and y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I created a stacked bar chart from the following dataframe:

```
df.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)
```

However, I wanted a chart with the X-Axis being the year and Y-Axis being the variables instead but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.T.plot(kind = 'bar', stacked = True)`
The `df.T`makes the transpose of the datframe and converts rows into columns